# Change header show the section

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, pagestyle

I want to change the head area. As soon as I change the head area I got the following error

```
Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.

 Learn more
\f@nch@olh ->\thechapter 
                         \ \leftmark \strut 
l.49 }
    
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

As soon as I change this (inside the `vorlage_winkelmann.tex`)

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} %Linie oben
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt} %Linie oben
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\headsep = 1cm
\fancyfoot[R]{\rule[+1.5ex]{0pt}{1ex}\thepage} %Kopfzeile rechts bzw. außen
\fancyfoot[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\newcommand{\JMUTitle}[9]{
            \fancyhead[L]{\rule[-1.5ex]{0pt}{1ex} #2} %Kopfzeile links bzw. innen
```

to this

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\thechapter\ \leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
% and remove the \fancyhead[L]{...}
\newcommand{\JMUTitle}[9]{
            %\fancyhead[L]{\rule[-1.5ex]{0pt}{1ex} #2} %Kopfzeile links bzw. innen
```

I got the error above

main.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}

\input{vorlage_winkelmann.tex}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Bibtex File einbinden %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



\addbibresource{literatur.bib}  


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Beginn des Dokuments  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{6pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{6pt}{0pt}

  \JMUTitle
      {Titel der Arbeit}                                % Titel der Arbeit
      {Kurztitel der Arbeit}                            % Muss in die Kopfzeile passen
      {Bachelorarbeit/Masterarbeit/Seminararbeit}       % Art der Arbeit
      {Nachname, Vorname }                              % Vor- und Nachname des Autors
      {TT.MM.JJJJ}                                      % Tag der Anemeldung 
      {TT.MM.JJJJ}                                      % Tag der Abgabe
      {Bachelor/Master Wirtschaftsinformatik}           % Studiengang
      {Prof. Dr. Axel Winkelmann}                       % Name des Betreuers -- Hier sollte *immer* Prof. Winkelmann stehen
      {1234567}                                         % Matrikelnummer 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Kurzzusammenfassung / Abstract  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\Zusammenfassung
{Zusammenfassung}
{Die Zusammenfassung dient dem Leser dazu, einen groben Überblick über die Inhalte zu gewinnen (kurze Problemstellung, Herangehensweise, Lösungsansätze und evtl. der Schlüsselerkenntnisse). Der Umfang sollte \underline{ca. eine halbe Seite} betragen. Auf der nächsten Seite soll eine Übersetzung der Zusammenfassung als Abstract in englischer Sprache erfolgen.

Allgemeiner Hinweis: Die „neue“ Rechtschreibung bietet viele alternative Rechtschreibmöglichkeiten. Es ist demnach egal, ob Sie z.B. Potenzial mit „z“ oder Potential mit „t“ schreiben. Auch das Komma kann vor einem erweiterten Infinitiv wahlweise gesetzt oder weggelassen werden. Alternative Schreibweisen bedeuten zugleich aber nicht Beliebigkeit. Sie sollten sich also immer konsequent während der gesamten Arbeit für \underline{eine} Schreibweise entscheiden. Dieses gilt auch für Fachbegriffe.
}

\Zusammenfassung
{Abstract}
{
Zusammenfassung der Seite i in englischer Sprache.

}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Inhaltsverzeichnis  %%
%%  wirt automatisch erstellt  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\tableofcontents


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Abbildungsverzeichnis %%
%%  wirt automatisch erstellt  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newpage

\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abbildungsverzeichnis (ab drei Abb.)}%
\markboth{Abbildungsverzeichnis (ab drei Abb.)}{Abbildungsverzeichnis (ab drei Abb.)}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Tabellenverzeichnis   %%
%%  wirt automatisch erstellt  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Tabellenverzeichnis}%
\markboth{Tabellenverzeichnis}{Tabellenverzeichnis}
\listoftables

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Abkürzungsverzeichnis %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newpage

\section*{Abkürzungsverzeichnis (nur bei Bachelor- und Masterthesis)}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}%
\markboth{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Abkürzungen %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{acronym}[ECU]
\acro{ecu}[ECU]{European currency unit}
\acro{eu}[EU]{Europäische Union}
\end{acronym}



\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
  
  
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Hauptteil  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\section{Einleitung} \label{einleitung}
Dieser Teil der Arbeit sollte folgende Inhalte haben:
\begin{itemize}
    \item Einführung in die Problemstellung
    \item Motivation und Herleitung des Themas
    \item Aufbau der Arbeit
\end{itemize}
Grundsätzlich sollten Kapitelüberschriften sprechend sein, das gilt insbesondere für das Einleitungskapitel, denn grundsätzlich ist das erste Kapitel immer ein einleitendes Kapitel. Der Leser würde also mit der Überschrift „Einleitung“ nichts über den Inhalt Ihres Kapitels erfahren. 

Hinweis:

Es hat sich als hilfreich erwiesen, die Einleitung mit der Zusammenfassung bzw. dem Abstract und der Schlussfolgerung zu vergleichen. Damit stellt man sicher, dass diese inhaltlich im Bezug auf Zielsetzung und Motivation übereinstimmen. Der Umfang sollte ca. 5\% der gesamten Arbeit betragen.



\end{document}
```

vorlange_winkelmann.tex

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%   Zusaetzliche Pakete  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{enumerate}  
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\RequirePackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,dashed=false,natbib=true,backend=biber,maxnames=2]{biblatex}
\usepackage[justification=centering, labelfont=bf, textfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=0cm, left=3cm, top=2.5cm, right=2cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setlength\cftparskip{-2pt}
\setlength\cftbeforesecskip{0pt}
\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{0pt}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{\fontsize{10}{0}\selectfont#1#2#3}
\captionsetup{format=myformat}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{0.8cm}

\linespread{1.25}

%\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{1.75pt}

\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Abbildung }
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{Tabelle }

\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{:}
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{:}

\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{2.75cm}
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{2cm}

\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0cm}

\renewcommand{\figurename}{Abbildung}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabelle}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Definition der Kopfzeile %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} %Linie oben
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt} %Linie oben
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\headsep = 1cm
\fancyfoot[R]{\rule[+1.5ex]{0pt}{1ex}\thepage} %Kopfzeile rechts bzw. außen
\fancyfoot[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}

% That don't work :/
%\pagestyle{fancy}
%\fancyhf{}
%\fancyhead[L]{\thechapter\ \leftmark}
%\fancyhead[R]{}
%\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
%\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Definition des Deckblattes und der Titelseite  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\JMUTitle}[9]{
  \fancyhead[L]{\rule[-1.5ex]{0pt}{1ex} #2} %Kopfzeile links bzw. innen
  % \fancyhead[L]{\rule[-1.5ex]{0pt}{1ex} #2} can't remove this above :(

  \thispagestyle{empty}
  
  \includegraphics[width=6.5in]{JMU.png}
  
  \begin{center}
    \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
    \Huge
    #1\\
    \vspace*{\stretch{0.25}}
    \normalsize
    #3
  \end{center}

  \vspace*{\stretch{2}}

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{l l} 
    Eingereicht von:  & \hspace{4cm}#4\\ 
    Studiengang:  & \hspace{4cm}#7\\ 
    Matrikelnummer:  & \hspace{4cm}#9\\ 
    Betreuer:  & \hspace{4cm}#8\\ 
    Bearbeitungszeit:  & \hspace{4cm}von  #5\\ 
                       & \hspace{4cm}bis  #6 \\
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{center}
    \vspace*{\stretch{1.5}}
    \includegraphics[width=1.75in]{siegel} \\
    \vspace*{\stretch{2}}
    Julius-Maximilians-Universität Würzburg \\
    \vspace*{\stretch{0.5}}
    Lehrstuhl für BWL und Wirtschaftsinformatik\\
    \vspace*{\stretch{0.5}}
    Sanderring 2, 97070 Würzburg\\
  \end{center}

\newpage

  \cleardoublepage
}

\newcommand{\Zusammenfassung}[2]{
    \section*{#1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
    \markboth{#1}{#1}
    \noindent
    #2
    \newpage
}
```

You can find the example here

https://de.overleaf.com/latex/templates/wissenschaftliche-arbeiten-lehrstuhl-bwl-und-wirtschaftsinformatik/fyyxhtdhkhpt

Comment: Can you change the documentclass from `article` to `report` or `book`, there a chapter is defined ...

Comment: Thank you, I have already done that. But then the whole formatting is messed up and before that, without changing anything, there are no errors, only when I change the header.

Comment: Add a minimal working example into the question itself, not external link. (also remove unnecessary things until it's minimal.)

Comment: @user202729 please see my edit.

Comment: The documentclass `article` does not provide chapters, so `\chapter`, `\chaptermark` and `\thechapter` are undefined. Maybe you want to use `\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}` and `\fancyhead[L]{\thesection\ \leftmark}`. Additionally you have to remove `\fancyhead[L]{...}` from the definition of `\JMUTitle`.

Comment: Would this do what you want:
`\fancyhead[L]{\ifnum\thesection=0\else\thesection\ \fi\leftmark}`

Comment: @PietervanOostrum thank you very much!! That worked! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Unfortunately this fails at the end when you switch over to `\section*` again. See my answer for a correct solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want two page styles: one with section numbers in the header, which is only useful for numbered sections (defined with `\section`), and one without section numbers when you use `\section*`.

The best way is to define two new page styles with `\fancypagestyle`, and put those `fancyhdr` definitions that are different there. Everything that they have in common can be defined in the normal way outside of these (but it doesn't harm to put them inside).

So put this in your definition file `vorlage_winkelmann.tex`:

```
\fancypagestyle{numbered}{\fancyhead[L]{\thesection\ \leftmark}}
\fancypagestyle{unnumbered}{\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}}
% Initial pagestyle
\pagestyle{unnumbered}
```

And then in your document file, use `\pagestyle{numbered}` just before the first `\section`.

```
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagestyle{numbered}  % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Hauptteil  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Einleitung} \label{einleitung}
```

And put `\pagestyle{unnumbered}` where the first `\section*` starts at the end of the document.

```
\newpage
\pagestyle{unnumbered} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\section*{Literaturverzeichnis} \label{Literaturverzeichnis}
```

Note that these are put *after* a `\newpage`, otherwise they may influence the layout of previous page.